# Can't make the serialized information to appear in the XML

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm running the following code:

```
public String Serialize()
{
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeInformation));
  StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
  serializer.Serialize(writer, new SomeInformation());
  String output = writer.ToString();
  return output;
}
```

With the serialization as follows.

```
[XmlRoot("MyRoot")]
public class SomeInformation
{
  public SomeInformation() { }

  [XmlElement("SomeNode1")]
  public String Prop1 { get { return "Some prop 1"; } }

  [XmlElement("SomeNode2")]
  public String Prop2 { get { return "Some prop 2"; } }
}
```

I'm getting the string to contain an XML but with no inner tags. I'm new to serialization and totally stuck. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?!

Comment: See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf00byt3.aspx): "Apply the XmlElementAttribute to **public fields** or **public read/write properties**"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are properties without a setter not serialized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401192/why-are-properties-without-a-setter-not-serialized)

Comment: @mellamokb My formulation is better. In order to find **that** other question one has to know that the setters missing are the problem. And by then, one knows the answer.

Answer (score 2):

XmlSerializer does not serialize read-only properties. Try adding empty setter to them.

For more details take a look at: [Why are properties without a setter not serialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401192/why-are-properties-without-a-setter-not-serialized)

Comment: I got it. Finally. I had removed the setters because I had another issue before. For some reason, I can't serialize e.g. *Uri* instances. Only string. Any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense to serialize read only properties. I would make `Prop1` and `Prop2` read/write properties and set them in code.

Comment: Why #1? I'm guessing it makes sense but I'm not sure what can go wrong. Please elaborate.

Comment: My bad. The XMLSerializer ignores the Serializable attribute for some reason. It is only required for serialization using serializers in System.Runtime.Serialization namespace. This does notably include the SoapSerializer.

Comment: +1 for cojones to admit the error. And for the clarity of answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're using read-only properties. Don't.

I just ran your class with the addition of empty setter and I get the data in the string.

```
[XmlRoot("MyRoot")]
public sealed class SomeInformation
{
  public SomeInformation() { }

  [XmlElement("SomeNode1")]
  public String Prop1 { get { return "Some prop 1"; } set { } }

  [XmlElement("SomeNode2")]
  public String Prop2 { get { return "Some prop 2"; } set { } }
}
```