# Serialize to XML a class containing a struct

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, struct

This is the class I'm trying to serialize

```
[Serializable]
public class PendingAccountInfo 
{
        public AccountId AccountId { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public struct AccountId : IEquatable<AccountId> 
{
    private readonly int _id;

    public AccountId(int id) {
        _id = id;
    }

    public int Id {
        get { return _id; }
    }
    ...
}
```

This is how I do the serialization

```
XmlSerializer xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent = true };

XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, settings);

xmlserializer.Serialize(writer, value);

string result = stringWriter.ToString();
```

This is what I get

```
<PendingAccountInfo>
  <AccountId />
  <EmailAddress>test@test.com</EmailAddress>
</PendingAccountInfo>
```

From what I read, this should work, but I must be missing something

Comment: Write a public getter/setter for property `Id`. An empty contructor may also be needed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here comes from your readonly property. As explained in this [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401192/why-are-properties-without-a-setter-not-serialized), XmlSerializer only serialize property with get/set accessibility.

What you can do is either make your property settable or change your serializer.

Comment: Thanks, I had already tried to make the property settable, but I forgot the property was readonly...