# Serialize derived read-only property

Tags: c#, serialization

I am serializing a data type to XML, and an exception is thrown:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException
```

The German error message is:

```
Es ist keine "set"-Methode für die "DerivedProperty"-Eigenschaft im Typ "MyApp.Models.MyEntry" implementiert.
```

Roughly translated, it tells me that an error occurred during serialization, because my read-only property "DerivedProperty" has no "set" method. But I won't implement a set method, as it is a read-only property, MyEntry is a serialization-only model (no deserialization on the server), and possibly because I am quite stubborn and hate such bad "solutions".

How do I tell .NET that my property is read-only and/or my model is serialization-only, so the exception goes away? My code is:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyEntry {
    internal string Property = null;
    [DataMember]
    public bool DerivedProperty {
        get {
            return Property == null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a discussion about this here:

[Why are properties without a setter not serialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401192/why-are-properties-without-a-setter-not-serialized)

In summary, it is a limitation of XmlSerializer, [DataContractSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) provides more flexibility.