# All my IsDirty flags are set to true after reading in a XML file using XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xmlserializer

I have a problem with implementing an `IsDirty` mechanism with my `XmlSerializer` system.

This is how my serialization is called:

```
public OCLMEditorModel()
{
    DeSerialize();
}

public void Serialize()
{
    XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(_ModelData.GetType());
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(_strPathModelDataXml))
    {
        x.Serialize(writer, _ModelData);
    }
}

public void DeSerialize()
{
    _ModelData = new OCLMModelData();
    XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(_ModelData.GetType());
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_strPathModelDataXml))
    {
        _ModelData = (OCLMModelData)x.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

It reads and saves perfectly, no issues there. But it is the `IsDirty` flag I have issues with. Directly after the DeSerialize call ...

[image: Set to true]

Ass the IsDirty are set to true. Even though all we have done is read it in from the computer. Example properties:

```
public class MaterialItem
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Setting
    {
        get { return _Setting; }
        set
        {
            _Setting = value;
            MarkDirty();
        }
    }
    private string _Setting;

    [XmlText]
    public string Material
    {
        get { return _Material; }
        set
        {
            _Material = value;
            MarkDirty();
        }
    }
    private string _Material;

    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool IsDirty { get { return _isDirty; } }
    private bool _isDirty;

    public void MarkClean()
    {
        _isDirty = false;
    }

    protected void MarkDirty()
    {
        _isDirty = true;
    }

    public MaterialItem()
    {
        MarkClean();
    }
}
```

Ideally, the flag should be false when we have just read it using XMLSerializer.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: When the object is being deserialized, it is setting the value on the property and in the property setter, `MarkDirty()` is being called which marks everything as dirty.

Comment: step thru the code and see where it's doing or not doing what you expect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` doesn't work in any mysterious way.

It uses reflection, yes, but only to [get the properties it can serialize/deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401192/why-are-properties-without-a-setter-not-serialized). Then it uses those properties to get/set the required values.

So during the deserialization those setters will be called, thus calling the `MarkDirty` method, thus marking your entities dirty.

There isn't anything you can change in `XmlSerializer`, but you can change your deserialization method, so it sets the entity clean just after deserializing it:

```
public void DeSerialize()
{
    _ModelData = new OCLMModelData();
    XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(_ModelData.GetType());
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_strPathModelDataXml))
    {
        _ModelData = (OCLMModelData)x.Deserialize(reader);
    }
    _ModelData.MarkClean();
}
```

Comment: @AndrewTruckle There is absolutely nothing wrong with adding additional information to the topic, but it is usually [frowned upon when the topic itself is changed drastically](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300966/dealing-with-solutions-that-end-with-a-new-error) - in such a case it is better to ask a new question, while linking to the current one to give the necessary context.

Comment: It is not a new question ... :) Just updated it. Please see bottom.

Comment: Thanks. I will stick with just making a MarkClean method which parses the read in data. Thank you. :)

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Well, I wouldn't exactly agree that it is not a new question - initial question was about why does it happen, while now it is more about what are the alternatives. I'd rather asked a new question along the line of "Managing a single isdirty flag on top of objects hierarchy" - it would be more concise and can potentially be very interesting to answerers.

Comment: We can delete these comments if you like. I removed it. :)

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Still you can ask that potential question - it may give you some alternative ideas.